# How to integrate Gmail API in php

Tags: php, google-api, composer-php, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I want access every thing that comes into the mail from user ( attachment of any type, html in mail body, images in body).

For that i am trying to access Gmail API referring from [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php),

I have followed step 1 success fully.

But I enable to install library using composer.
I have composer install but don't know how to use it.

Also  I will realy appreciate if i get more information on it.

Comment: are you using window or Linux ?

Comment: @SanjayKumar windows locally. But going to upload it on linux server

Comment: have you installed a composer on window ?

Comment: i have installed a lib through composer https://prnt.sc/jqne0m

Comment: if a comoser installed on your window, then give a permission to your folder and write this command composer require google/apiclient:^2.0

Answer (score 0):

### Tutorial

From the tutorial you [linked](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php)

> Step 2: Install the Google Client Library
>   Run the following command to install the library using composer:
>
> ```
> php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0
> ```
>
> See the library's installation page for the alternative installation options.

### Client Library

Directly from the [PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

#### Composer

The preferred method is via [composer](https://getcomposer.org). Follow the
[installation instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) if you do not already have
composer installed.

Once composer is installed, execute the following command in your project root to install this library:

`sh
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0`

Finally, be sure to include the autoloader:

`php
require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';`